# Calling a Translate Program using a Dictionary program that will be called back to program

Tags: java, process, jar, inputstream, runtime.exec

I am a complete noob in coding and I was wondering if I can get some help

I have this project see and basically what I need to do is:

> Create 2 executable programs.  A Translate Program, and a Dictionary Program. The programs can be written in any language.
>
> The Translate program will pass the Dictionary program an English word.  The Dictionary program will translate and return a foreign word.  The Translate program will print out the English word and it’s translation into a file.
>
> The Dictionary program will look up the English word and return its translation in foreign language.    The Dictionary program will have the ability to translate a selected number of English words into another language.  The language the Dictionary program will translate English words to will be determined by the student.  The Dictionary program will have the ability to translate at least 15 English words into a foreign language. "

Right now I am having trouble having the Dictionary program call the Translate program.
My instructor told us to use the statement

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar Translate.jar"); 

InputStream in = proc.getInputStream();
InputStream err= proc.getErrorStream();
```

Currently the problem is that my program doesn't seem to have access to the jar file.
I am using Eclipse and Windows 7 
The steps I did to create the Translate jar file was to

1. right-click the Translate project
2. export
3. Selected Runnable Jar File
4. Chose Dictionary - Dictionary as the Launch configuration
5. Typed in Dictionary\Translate.jar as the Export Destination
6. Clicked finish and then proceeded to try and use Process runtime

Right now I only have pseudo-codes for both programs but I am focusing on figuring out how to call the translate program.

## Dictionary.java

```
public class Dictionary {

    public static void main(String [] args){

        /******************
         * Dictionary Program 
         * Will translate and return a foreign word back 
         * to the Translate program that this Program is calling.
         * It will look up the English word. The Dictionary will use
         * Elvish as the foreign language that is being translated.
         * Should be able to translate 15 english words.
         */

            /**********************************************************
            /* External  Module code  calls Translate and gets output
             *from module
            /*********************************************************/

        /*  try
            {
                // Run a java app in a separate system process 
                Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar Translate.jar"); 

                // Then retreive the process output 
                InputStream in = proc.getInputStream();
                InputStream err= proc.getErrorStream();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
                String EngWord = reader.readLine();   //EngWord is the variable sent from the Translate program


                while ( (EngWord = reader.readLine()) != null)
                       do //Pseudo-code of (If, Else Statements provided below)






        /**********************************************************************
         * Pseudo-code
         **********************************************************************/
        String EngWord = "Should be a variable that the Translate Program is passing that is the english word";
        String foreignWord = "A variable created by this Diction program that will be sent back to the Translate program";

        if (EngWord == "dog") {
            foreignWord = "elvish equivalent";
        } else if (EngWord == "cat") {
            foreignWord = "cat in elvish";
        } else if (EngWord == "tree"){
            foreignWord = "tree in elven";
        }  else {

            EngWord = "nothing? something that can end the loop well";
            // I guess this is where the loop must terminate 
        }

        //Must find a way to return the foreignWord back to Translate

       /* 
       } catch (Throwable e){
        e.printStackTrace();
       } 
        */
    }   
}
```

### Translate.java

```
public class Translate {

    /**************************
     * Translate program will pass the Dictionary program
     * an English word. When the Dictionary program translate and returns an Elvish word
     * This program will print out the English word and its translation into a file
     * 
     */
    public static void main(String [] args) {

        //Must find a way to pass the english word to Dictionary

        String EngWord = "This is the variable being sent to the Dictionary program...use as parameter?";

        //Must use some type of Writer class in order to write the output of both the EngWord and foreignWord
        //into an Output file

        String foreignWord = "THis is the variable being sent back from the Dictionary program";
        //perhaps use runtime before this so Translate can retreive foreignWord from Dictionary?

        //Some type of algorithm that will write both the foreignWord and Engword onto an output file.
        //Prints (Writes) out to "output.txt"
    }

}
```

If I am not allowed to receive such amount of help can someone perhaps tell me what other websites I may be allowed to post this request?

Comment: *"My instructor told us to use the statement"*  Is the point of this exercise to learn how to use a `Process` or to connect a Java based class to another Java class (in another jar)?  The latter is much more useful (and simple).

Comment: I believe it is the latter since he said he only recommended to use Process. However it does seem like the most effective one i am assuming since the rest of my classmates are using it. Then i again I dont know any better. But yes the primary purpose of the project is to call another java based class in a form of a jar file